# onError behaving differently between browsers

Tags: javascript, css, image, onerror

I'm trying to get the onError event to work but so far it only works in Internet Explorer 9. I have tried several codes but basically it comes down to this:

```
<img class="a_toc_image" src="' + asap.imgurl + '" onError="this.src=\'images/no_image.png\';" />
```

- *Internet Explorer 9:*
- Success: Gets an image from our database
- Fail   : **Displays no_image.png**
- *Chrome 20.0.11:*
- Success: Gets an image from our database
- Fail   : **Just whitespace**
- *Firefox 14.0.1:*
- Success: Gets an image from our database
- Fail   : **Broken image icon**

Many mostly aesthetical variants on this code ( such as leaving out or putting in " or ' ) yield similar results. This specific variant yielded a stack overflow in Iexplorer but otherwise nothing changed:

```
<img class="a_toc_image" src="' + asap.imgurl + '" onError=this.src="\images/no_image.png()" />
```

Who can tell me what is going wrong here and why it will only work in Iexplorer 9?

Thanks!

### -Addition:

When using "inspect element" in Chrome on an image that fails to load I see this:

```
<img class="a_toc_image" src="images/no_image.png" onerror="this.src='images/no_image.png';">
```

So it looks like it is generating the correct output but for some reason won't show the image, correct? I have tried to put a .jpg instead of .png just now (maybe Chrome would just not show .png images) but that also does not solve anything.

-Addition 2, preceding code

```
// General functions

var open_mask = function () {

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("fast",0.7);  

};

var center_dialog = function (dialog) {

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    var dialog_top =  (winH/2-dialog.height()/2) + $(window).scrollTop();
    var dialog_left = (winW/2-dialog.width()/2) + $(window).scrollLeft();

    dialog_top = (dialog_top >= 0) ? dialog_top : 0;
    dialog_left = (dialog_left >= 0) ? dialog_left : 0;

    dialog.css('top',  dialog_top);
    dialog.css('left', dialog_left);
};


//function that creates posts  

var updatepostHandler = function(postsJSON) {

    $.each(postsJSON,function(i,asap) {  

        if(i === 0) {
            first = asap.first;
            last = asap.last;
        } else {
            if(asap.type === 'article') {
                $('<div></div>')                        //create the HTML
                            .addClass('solid')  
                    .html('<div class="titbox">' + asap.title + '</div> \
                        <div class="boxinsolid"> \
                        <div class="aubox">' + asap.authors + '</div> \
                        <div class="doibox"> DOI: ' + asap.doi + ' </div> \
                        <div class="joubox">' + asap.journal + '</div> \
                        </div> \
                        <div class="imgbox"> \
                                <img class="a_toc_image" src="' + asap.imgurl + '" onError="this.src=\'images/no_image.png\';" /> \
                        </div>')        

                            .click(function(e) {  
                        open_details(e, asap.id);
                                })  
                            .prependTo($('#container'))
                    .slideDown('slow') 
            } else if(asap.type === 'ad') {
                $('<div></div>')                        //create the HTML
                            .addClass('ad')  
                    .html('<div class="titbox">' + asap.title + '</div> \
                        <div class="boxinsolid"> \
                        <div class="aubox">' + asap.authors + '</div> \
                        <div class="doibox">&nbsp;</div> \
                        <div class="joubox">' + asap.company + '</div> \
                        </div> \
                        <div class="imgbox"> \
                                <img class="a_toc_image" src="' + asap.image + '" onError="this.src=\'images/no_image.png\';" /> \
                        </div>')                        

                            .click(function(e) {  
                        open_details(e, asap.ad_id);
                                })  
                            .prependTo($('#container'))
                    .slideDown('slow') 
            }



        };

          });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it in Chrome and FF it seems that the problem is the (unnecessary) backslashes before your single quote characters.
See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yapad/

So, you should use this code, instead of your code:

```
<img class="a_toc_image" src="' + asap.imgurl + '" onerror="this.src='images/no_image.png';">
```

**Edit:**
Sidestepping the issue with proper handling of asap.imgurl would look like this:

```
<img class="a_toc_image" src="' + (asap.imgurl != "" ? asap.imgurl:"/images/no_image.png") + '">
```

Comment: Well after this I get something I have seen before in other attempts, only my header/logo loads and the rest won't appear. I have no access to it now but Aptana in this case would already give some warning that something is wrong. All browsers respond similar here. Maybe something is wrong in some other code on my page? Thanks for the attempt anyway!

Comment: Could you set up a demonstration page somewhere so we could have a look at a live example of the problem? =) Your code seems to be correct and from what I could test in jsFiddle, it _should_ work.

Comment: I just had a look at your code - wouldn't it be easier to simply check if asap.imgurl is empty (== "") and in that case replace it with the fallback default image? Other than that, there problem could be caused by switchting the image while sliding / fading in.

Comment: Yes that would indeed be easier I suppose :) Since I am just a beginner, would you have a line of code for that? I did not know that also existed, was looking for it though. I am mainly responsible for the HTML/CSS part of the website (and even there I have little experience but it is going quite okay I guess :)

Comment: I think you're right, it should work indeed. But the odd thing is that as soon as I remove the slashes / from the code that the whole element the code is for won't load anymore. -edit removed part of the post to temporarily put it in the opening post :)

Comment: I added to my answer a line of code that would check whether asap.imgurl is empty and in that case replace it with the fallback URL.

Comment: Awesome tnx, I am going to try that tomorrow! (less alcohol consumed hehe)