# How can I remove default image icon

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

**Images in which I have facing the cross sign problem which is appear in chrome and IE**
[image]
**the scenario which i want from external java script file(i want something like this).**
[image]

first image having a cross icon when image tag not find the image from the source. mozilla will handle this very smartly but chrome and IE show a cross icon which i don't want..

i find out the solution which is not generic i have to pass a transparent image url when image not getting the image from specified url on every image tag..
something like this

```
<img src="i/ibm.png" onerror="this.src='i/1x1trns.png';">
```

but in my page there are more than 20 image and in a whole project more than 200 so in that case i want to handle this from a single external javascript file ...

so any one how know about this problem please tell me a solution...Thnx for co-operation

Comment: Have you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794658/onerror-behaving-differently-between-browsers

Comment: yes i see this link but here "onerror" is apply on img tag, not from the external files which i don't want because it' very dirty coding way to add "onerror" tag on each image tag... so i want to handle this from one place

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    (function(img_elem) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = img_elem.src;
        img.onerror = function() {
             img_elem.src = 'i/1x1trns.png';
        };
    })(imgs[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ypa7N/

Comment: i have tried your code but it's not working in all the browser

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit dirty to have jQuery defined in the `<head />` tag but you'd need to do this for `$.ready`, if you can write your own `$.ready` then it'd be just a bit of code in our `<head />`.

**OR**

You'd need to add jQuery before you have those images.

Try this code

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("img").on("error", function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "i/1x1trns.png");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <img src="not-a-valid-image.png" alt="Logo not found" />
</body>
```

I have used this way in one of my projects.

Comment: i have tried your code but it's not working in IE browser and also i want code written only in java script because i am not using jquery in my project